# Getting deprecated warning

Tags: android, database, sqlite, deprecated

As the title implies I am getting Deprecated warning while trying to compile. I have analyzed my code and got the following 2 errors on my database site. So I am assuming that this is where the error is ?

The first error appears here. Right after FROM there is a red marker, the error reads

> (table or subquery) expected, unexpected end of file.

```
   if (filter.equals("")) {
        query = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_name;
    }else {
```

The second error is below.

> (Single table statement table) expected unexpected end of  file

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are facing is in the line `db.execSQL`,Try to do like this and it will not show you the Deprecated warning

```
String query = "Select * FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+ROUTE_ID+ "= " + RouteID;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    setAlarmDynamic setalarmDynamics  = new setAlarmDynamic();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ROUTE_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {
            String.valueOf(setalarmDynamics.getRouteId())

        });
        cursor.close();
    }

    db.close();
```